# Cross compiling portaudio for ARM architecture

Tags: c++, makefile, arm, gnu, portaudio

I want to cross compile portaudio in order to use it on a ARM system (devkit8000). I am trying to use cross compilation tools given with this board (arm-none-linux-gnueabi) in this way

```
CXX=../cross/arm-2007q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ ./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux
```

but when I try to link portaudio object with my source code compiled it tells me

```
../cross/arm-2007q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -L../portaudio/lib/.libs -lportaudio prova.cpp 
../portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Check for ARM libraries in this path `./portaudio/lib` ARM libs generally have `.a` extension. `.so` is generally on x86

Comment: Yes, it was compiling with x86 gcc, thanks. maybe I found a solution: I put my cross compilation bin path in PATH variable, and then I called configure in this way `CC=../cross/arm-2007q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=../cross/arm-2007q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ ./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi` . Compilation of my source code now returns with no error.. I'll try to deploy it in the board now

Comment: If all is well, do tell me. I shall put in my comment as answer so that you can accept it ;-)

Comment: I can recommend pkg-config for setting up the paths in a nice way for crosscompiling if you think you are gonna have many of these conflicts in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used bitbake and openembedded. Just adding to my bitbake recipe

```
DEPENDS = "portaudio-v19"
```

bitbake builds portaudio for your machine and you have only to copy `ipk` package (in my case, using `Angstrom 2012.05`) from `tmp/deploy/...` subdirectory to your system and install it with (in `Angstrom 2012.05`):

```
opkg install <package_name>.ipk
```